# Using boot2docker in OSX

Tags: macos, docker

i need little hlp with docker in osx, everything works fine with boot2docker but a need to forward ssh-agent socket to docker container.  When I forward /private/tmp to docker container with -v switch I can not see content of $SSH_AUTH_SOCKET

thx 
Marek

Comment: Please develop your problem and enrich it with relevant pieces of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the OSX boot2docker setup only works for folders under `/Users/`, so your folder will be inside your boot2docker container, not on your client.

Your best option is probably to modify the location of the ssh-agent socket file. ssh-agent has an -a option which might be worth looking into.

Comment: This might be a good starting point `docker run --rm -v ~/:/target nematix/boot2docker-tool && source ~/.profile`